# facing failed to lazily initialize a collection and could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

When i send post request from angular then in spring boot requestfilter program showing error while validating the jwt token.

facing issue `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`:

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   in.yis.mains.model.OpsUsersLogin.roles, could not initialize proxy -
>   no Session

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(
        name="ops_users_login",
        uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username"})}
    )
public class OpsUsersLogin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String oldPassword;

    private String status_flag;

    private int wrong_attampts;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date created_date;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date expiry_date;


    private long rights;

    private String address;

    private String designation;

    private long empId;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date created_by;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date updated_by;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "opsUsersLogin_roles", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
    private Collection<Role> roles;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This describes what you need basically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358189/jpa-with-hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-fetching-all-data)

The `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` means, that a related entity or collection of entities, in your case `roles` , has not been initialized yet, as the default fetch strategy of a related entity is `LAZY`.

To fix this you have to initilize the `roles` collection after fetching the `ops_user_login` entity or you can just fetch them through a query, if you are already using one to fetch your entity. Initializing the `roles` can be done with `Hibernate.initialize(entity.getRoles())`, if that does not work you can also just call `entity.getRoles().size()` as a workaround.

If you are using a query to select your `ops_user_login` you can do something similar to this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
    "from ops_user_login o " +
    "join fetch o.roles"
);
```

or

```
TypedQuery<OpsUsersLogin> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select o from ops_user_login o join fetch o.roles", OpsUsersLogin.class);
```